# MySQL - Top 5 rank best seller plans or courses

Tags: mysql5

I sell subscriptions of my online course, as well as the courses in retail.
I would bring the "top 5" of best selling plans / courses. For this, I have a table called "subscriptionPlan", which stores the purchased plan ID, or in the case of a course, the course ID, and the amount spent on this transaction. Example:

**table subscriptionPlan**

```
sbpId | subId | plaId | couId | sbpAmount
1     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 499.99
2     | 2     | 1     | 2     | 499.99
3     | 3     | 2     | 0     | 899.99
4     | 4     | 1     | 1     | 499.99
```

Just for educational purposes, plaId = 1 is a plan called "Single Sale" that I created, to maintain the integrity of the DB. When the couId isn't empty, you also have bought a separate course, not a plan where you can attend any course.

My need is: List the top 5 sales. If it is a plan, display the plan name (plan table, column plaTitle). If it is a course, display its name (table course, colna couTitle). This logic that I can't code. I was able to rank a top 5 of PLANS, but it groups the courses, since the GROUP BY is by the ID of the plan. I believe the prank is here, maybe creating an IF / ELSE in this GROUPBY, but I don't know how to do this.

The query that i code, to rank my top 5 plans is:

```
SELECT sp.plaId, sp.couId, p.plaTitle, p.plaPermanent, c.couTitle, SUM(sbpAmount) AS sbpTotalAmount
FROM subscriptionPlan sp
LEFT JOIN plan p ON sp.plaId = p.plaId
LEFT JOIN course c ON sp.couId = c.couId
GROUP BY sp.plaId
ORDER BY sbpTotalAmount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The result that i expected was:

```
plaId | couId | plaTitle        | couTitle   | plaPermanent | sbpTotalAmount
1     | 1     | Venda avulsa    | Curso 01   | true         | 999.98
2     | 0     | Acesso total    | null       | false        | 899.99
3     | 2     | Venda avulsa    | Curso 02   | true         | 499.99
```

How could I get into this query formula?

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: 5.x, @TheImpaler!

Answer (score 0):

When grouping you can use:

- Simple columns, or
- Any [complex] expression.

In your case, it seems you need to group by an expression, such as:

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN sp.plaId = 1 THEN -1 ELSE sp.couId END
```

In this case I chose `-1` as the grouping for the "Single Plan". You can replace the value for any other that doesn't match any `couId`.